# Is it possible to read from dataframe in a merge operation

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

In the below sample **product_new** is a dataframe. is it possible to use **product_new** directly in the merge operation instead of declaring as a temp table? currently **product_new** dataframe stored as a temptable named  **product_new_temp** and this is used in merge operation. is there anyway directly call **product_new** dataframe in the merge operation? when i use **product_new** directly in the merge it gives me invalid table/view error. spark/databricks

```
product = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').load("/FileStore/tables/product-1.csv")
product.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("product_delta_table")

product_new = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').load("/FileStore/tables/product_delta.csv")
product_new.createOrReplaceTempView("product_new_temp")


%sql
MERGE INTO product_delta_table
USING **product_new_temp**
ON product_delta_table.productCode = **product_new_temp**.productCode
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *;

select * from product_delta_table order by productCode
```

Comment: what about union both dataframe then insert ?

Comment: Thanks Maxime. checking is it possible to use dataframe directly in the merge without declaring it as a delta table or temp table.